# Antlr4 C# build error

Tags: c#, antlr, antlr4

I am trying to install Antlr4 on a new machine but I am getting the following build error:

> C:\antlrtest\antlrtest\Reference\Antlr4\Antlr4.targets(129,5): error AC1000: Unknown build error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

This is the offending code:

```
<Antlr4ClassGenerationTask
  ToolPath="$(Antlr4ToolLocation)"
  BuildTaskPath="$(Antlr4BuildTaskLocation)"
  OutputPath="$(IntermediateOutputPath)"
  TargetLanguage="%(Antlr4.TargetLanguage)"
  TargetFrameworkVersion="$(TargetFrameworkVersion)"
  TargetNamespace="%(Antlr4.CustomToolNamespace)"
  SourceCodeFiles="@(Antlr4)"
  ContinueOnError="$(_IntellisenseOnlyCompile)"
  TokensFiles="@(Antlr4Tokens)"
  AbstractGrammarFiles="@(Antlr4AbstractGrammar)"
  LanguageSourceExtensions="$(DefaultLanguageSourceExtension)"
  GenerateListener="%(Antlr4.Listener)"
  GenerateVisitor="%(Antlr4.Visitor)"
  ForceAtn="%(Antlr4.ForceAtn)"
  AbstractGrammar="%(Antlr4.Abstract)">

  <Output ItemName="Antlr4GeneratedCodeFiles" TaskParameter="GeneratedCodeFiles" />
</Antlr4ClassGenerationTask>
```

I think I followed the correct procedure:

I installed the extension from the VS 2012 website for Antlr.
Then I edited the project file to point to the References.
Then I added a reference to the Runtime DLL.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I solved it.  The problem was in the Java installation.

Comment: Can you say exactly was the problem with your Java installation? I am having the same issue on a build server - but not my own machine. Java 1.6 is installed and in the path.

Comment: That was the problem.  The new machine I moved to did not have the JDK install and on the path.  Once I fixed that it worked.

Comment: You get the same error even if the environment variable, JAVA_HOME, points to a directory with a proper java JRE within the %JAVA_HOME%/bin directory.

Comment: Sam: is there any chance of repairing the error message so in this case you the AC1000: Unknown build error: Could not locate a Java installation error instead of the mis-leading error message: Unknown build error: The system cannot find the file specified ~\packages\Antlr4.4.3.0\build\Antlr4.targets?

Comment: Hate to resurrect an old question but I'm running into this.  VS2015, Antlr4.5 alpha 003.  I've now installed JDK and set JAVA_HOME env. variable as well, but no luck.  Any particulars anyone can remember that is not mentioned here?

Answer (score 1):

So I ran into this today and was pulling my hair out over it for quite some time.  The solution for me was to install both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of the Java SDK.

Initially I only had the 64-bit version installed. It immediately started working after I installed the 32-bit as well.

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

This error is caused by Antlr4 failing to find an appropriate version of Java. On a Windows machine, Antlr4 checks the registry first *before* it checks your environment variables to determine the suitable location of Java.

Shortly before I experienced the same problem, I had been consolidating the many instances of the Java Runtime Environment I had on my computer. I had *many* and I trimmed them down to only 1 instance of a 64b JRE and 32b JRE each. I removed the rest by just deleting their folders. Subsequently I checked that my user and system environment variables (specifically `JAVA_HOME`) still pointed to a valid Java directory.

But I failed to realise that there are registry entries that have to be updated too. Possibly a reinstall of Java would fix the registry entries, but I reverted to just fixing them manually.

So the appropriate place in the Antlr4 code is at https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4cs/blob/master/runtime/CSharp/Antlr4BuildTasks/Antlr4ClassGenerationTaskInternal.cs#L144 .

```
       private string JavaHome
        {
            get
            {
#if !NETSTANDARD
                string javaHome;
                if (TryGetJavaHome(RegistryView.Default, JavaVendor, JavaInstallation, out javaHome))
                    return javaHome;

                if (TryGetJavaHome(RegistryView.Registry64, JavaVendor, JavaInstallation, out javaHome))
                    return javaHome;

                if (TryGetJavaHome(RegistryView.Registry32, JavaVendor, JavaInstallation, out javaHome))
                    return javaHome;
#endif

                if (Directory.Exists(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("JAVA_HOME")))
                    return Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("JAVA_HOME");

                throw new NotSupportedException("Could not locate a Java installation.");
            }
        }

#if !NETSTANDARD
        private static bool TryGetJavaHome(RegistryView registryView, string vendor, string installation, out string javaHome)
        {
            javaHome = null;

            string javaKeyName = "SOFTWARE\\" + vendor + "\\" + installation;
            using (var baseKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, registryView))
            {
                using (RegistryKey javaKey = baseKey.OpenSubKey(javaKeyName))
                {
                    if (javaKey == null)
                        return false;

                    object currentVersion = javaKey.GetValue("CurrentVersion");
                    if (currentVersion == null)
                        return false;

                    using (var homeKey = javaKey.OpenSubKey(currentVersion.ToString()))
                    {
                        if (homeKey == null || homeKey.GetValue("JavaHome") == null)
                            return false;

                        javaHome = homeKey.GetValue("JavaHome").ToString();
                        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(javaHome);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
#endif
```

Your `.\packages\Antlr4.CodeGenerator.4.6.3\build\Antlr4.CodeGenerator.targets` file (adjust for correct version number) has lines to set the `JavaVendor` and `JavaInstallation` variables:

```
    <Antlr4JavaVendor Condition="'$(Antlr4JavaVendor)'==''">JavaSoft</Antlr4JavaVendor>
    <Antlr4JavaInstallation Condition="'$(Antlr4JavaInstallation)'==''">Java Runtime Environment</Antlr4JavaInstallation>
```

So, in my case at least, the appropriate registry settings were located in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment`

To fix the incorrect registry:

- Ensure that `CurrentVersion`'s value (in my case `1.8.0_91`) has a corresponding key
- Ensure that the `JavaHome` key in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\1.8.0_91` (replace with your version) has a directory path to a valid Java installation.
- If you're running a 64b Windows, ensure this for both the 64b and 32b versions of the registry (see https://support.microsoft.com/fr-dz/help/305097/how-to-view-the-system-registry-by-using-64-bit-versions-of-windows for how to view the 32b registry on a 64b machine).

Keep in mind, that Visual Studio is a 32b process and that, by default, it will run Antlr4 by looking for a 32b version of the JRE.  If, for some reason, you're building the solution outside of Visual Studio with 64b processes, the 64b version of the registry is used.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Visual Studio 2022 and I had to compile a project that used Antlr4.4.5.3. The grammar file was configured to generate a Visitor but it did not work. I had the same error as you.

In my case I had an Open JDK in my JAVA_HOME environment variable. I also had an Oracle Java JDK installed. So, I deduced that Antl4 did not like my JAVA_HOME pointing to the Open JDK.

So I deleted the JDK and JRE folders (that pointed to the Open JDK) at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft in the registry allowing me to compile my project successfully.

I deduce that Antlr then used the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment folder where the configuration is set when you install an Oracle Java JDK version.

Comment: It's best not to use that old fork of Antlr4. A lot has changed, and at some point, we will pour all "optimizations" from the fork back into the "official" Antlr code. Put in your .csproj `<ItemGroup><PackageReference Include="Antlr4.Runtime.Standard" Version ="4.11.1" /><PackageReference Include="Antlr4BuildTasks" Version = "12.1" PrivateAssets="all" /></ItemGroup>`. The package will pick up the right version of Java to generate .cs files: it tests your Java version and chooses to work with it if compatible with Antlr 4.11.1. Otherwise, it'll download and unpack a JRE that works for your OS.